# tags: grammars vs formal-grammars

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have two tags at the moment which seem to be the same topic. I think we should make one the synonym for the other. So my suggestion is to merge [formal-grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-grammars) into [grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars).

Comment: It's better to be compatible with other sites, if we don't have a reason to do things differently. What do [so], [cstheory.se] and [math.se] have?

Comment: @Gilles, on [cstheory.se] we have grammars, on [math.se] there is not a similar tag, on [so] they have grammar and grammars (the first is more often used).

Comment: I think [tag:formal-grammar] should be preferred and [tag:grammar] a synonym.

Comment: @Raphael, I lean towards the latter because I feel `formal` is redundant here and I haven't heard anyone call them as such.

Comment: @Kaveh We say it most of the time (when precision is called for). I think it is worthwhile to separate formal grammars from grammars of natural languages. I do not know how NLP people use the term; we should avoid conflicts there.

Comment: @Raphael, the [tag:formal-languages] tag should suffice to make sure it is not confused with a question in NLP and computational linguistics.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/128/98) question intended to collect all synonymous tags.

Comment: @Raphael, grammars for natural languages tend to be formal grammars as well, just not unambiguous formal grammars.  A GLR parser's language model is as much a formalization as any BNF grammar.

Answer (score 3):

I've merged [grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars) into [formal-grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-grammars), because the use count was 2 vs 11. The direction can easily be reversed. Should it?

Comment: I am in favor of the reverse direction, but it is not a very important issue.

Comment: +1 since I don't think we need both, but I think I'd favor the other direction as well.

Comment: Pro merge, and pro the direction you merged; NLP people might make questions in the future concerning non-formal grammars (?).